# Updating free youtube gallery to work with Youtube 3.0 API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Youtube 3.0 is going to kill off some useful slider code, instead I want to get it updated.

To start off, I've looked through the API and the migration tips and the deprecated functions lists, and it makes sense. However I'm not familiar enough with how this gallery was coded to easily update this to function on 3.0 quickly.

So i figured I'd ask the question on here to see if anyone can get it done sooner to save some time.

I did not code this! This was distributed under the apache license and made by Simone Gianni. It's been useful for me and many others so I want it to be updated and continue being useful for everyone.

The Original: http://jsfiddle.net/NmvA9/490/

I'm pretty sure at this point that everything is fine except for the use of getJSON which is deprecated in 3.0.

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/' + allopts.user + '/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=?', null, function(data) {
            var feed = data.feed;
            var videos = [];
            $.each(feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
                var video = {
                    title: entry.title.$t,
                    id: entry.id.$t.match('[^/]*$'),
                    thumbnails: entry.media$group.media$thumbnail
                };
                videos.push(video);
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to jlmcdonald for the help. You really rocketed me forward on this. You were right by the way, it was the thumbnails, or so I thought? Once resolving all the problems with the thumbnails i'm left with what seems to be blank returns for no reason. Viewable here: http://jsfiddle.net/ynAtb/10/

Not sure why, I'm assuming I'm making a valid get to the wrong place.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a couple of caveats:

1) In V3 of the YouTube API, any read request will require an API key, which each developer has to get on his/her own at http://console.developers.google.com. This will make it so that, if you are redistributing the new code, it won't be truly plug and play ... devs will have to edit it to include their own API key in the relevant location.

2) You might need to slightly change any code that actually implements the thumbnails ... the thumbnail object in V3 uses different parameter names for the various types of thumbnails.

Anyway, having said that, here's how you'd translate the above code to V3:

```
    var videos = [];
    $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername='+allopts.user+'&key=', function(channeldata) {
        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=id,snippet&channelId='+channeldata.items[0].id+'&key=', function(videodata) {
            $.each(videodata.items, function(k,v) {
              var video = {
                        title: v.snippet.title,
                        id: v.id.videoId,
                        thumbnails: v.snippet.thumbnails
              };
              videos.push(video);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I'm having some trouble with the code you supplied, testing it here. http://jsfiddle.net/ynAtb/8/ (I've added my key, which I'll delete when this is resolved).

The issue is on the each loop line, it says Unexpected identifier. This may be due to the thumbnails? Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry about that. My copying and pasting went awry and truncated some of the code! it's been edited above.

Comment: there were two problems; as I mentioned, the thumbnail object is a bit different now. Rather than taking the first indexed thumb, there's a 'default' property, ones for other resolutions, etc. The other thing to note is that the YouTube API is asynchronous, so the video results hadn't returned yet by the time your code was trying to create a player, One way around this is to move your code to create the player inside the success function of the ajax call. Another would be to use promises instead of nested ajax calls.  I forked and modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/ynAtb/11

Comment: Thank you so much jlmcdonald! You're a life saver. Works great and now I see the merit of 3.0, now that it works.